# Text track matte with CSS

Tags: css, text, alpha

So, i was coding something and idea comed to my mind. I couldn't get to the bottom of it, and figure out how to do it, so I'm hoping someone else is also interested. :)

Is it possible to do a Track matte (like in after effects) in CSS with text. So cut text of a div to see background of the bottom div. Like this:

[image: text track matted]

Is it even possible to do it only with code, without using images. So, thanks, best regards.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: This article is also interesting: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/02/techniques-for-creating-textured-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yep but only for webkits**

Interesting is also:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/

```
.backgroundclip h1 {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background: url(http://bit.ly/1hRsB2d) no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

**Demo** (as is in comment) on:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageUnderText/

Comment: so this does the job, althought it only works in -webkit-s, but hey, it works. here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DCbgc/) of a fiddle.